# Give string numeric value

Tags: java, string, int, numeric

How do I assign a numeric value to a string in Java? I'm using cards from Ace to king, and I want to assign the value 11 to "Jack" so I can compare it to, say, "Six".
Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on what language you are using. What language *are* you using?

Comment: Awfully sorry, Java. That was stupid of me to forget.

Comment: I only looked at the tags. Apologies if I skimmed over the "in Java" in the question itself.

Comment: No, I added that in after, don't worry.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You most likely want an enumeration. See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and then update this question if you have a specific problem implementing such a solution.  As this question is currently phrased, it's not about a specific programming issue and might be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a language which supports enums, those are probably your best bet.  For instance, in C#, you could do (this is rough and untested):

```
public enum CardDeck
{
1 = 1,
2 = 2,
3 = 3,
...
Jack = 10,
Queen = 11,
King = 12,
Ace = 13
}
```

You can then compare (if (int)Ace == (int)1) {}

Comment: +1 but you should probably delete your answer as OP has specified language is Java in the meantime. You might get downvotes from unaware people otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use HashMaps:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Jack", 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. You can, say, store the strings in an array and search for them, returning the index:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("ace");
names.add("two");
names.add("three");

int number = names.indexOf("ace");
```

You could use a map of strings to numbers and do a lookup, this allows use of nonconsecutive numbers:

```
Map<String,Integer> names = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
names.put("ace", 1);
names.put("jack", 11);
names.put("queen", 12);

int number = names.get("ace");
```

You could also use an enum with properties, e.g.:

```
enum CardValue {
  ACE(1),
  JACK(11),
  QUEEN(12);
  final int value;
  CardValue (int value) { this.value = value; } 
  int getValue () { return value; }
}

int number = Enum.valueOf(CardValue.class, "ace".toUpperCase()).getValue();
```

Or in the above you could use `ordinal()` if they are consecutive.

Add error handling as necessary.

You could also just use a brute force large `if`, or use a switch block (since Java 1.7):

```
int value (String name) {
    switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
    case "ace": return 1;
    case "jack": return 11;
    case "queen": return 12;
    default: return -1;
}
```

Personally, I'd go for the array or map approach in your case. It is simple to code and allows easy conversion of string to value and back, and, unlike the enum technique, doesn't tie compile-time type names to user input strings (e.g. difficult if you, say, add support for another language).

The switch block is easy to code as well.

Comment: I already have an array made that picks a card at random `String [] arrRank = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
      "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };
          Random randomRank = new Random();`

I just need to be able to compare these ranked cards. I'm not sure how to implement your ideas.

Comment: @ematoeldiablo Two things: 1) We have no way of knowing what you already have, since you did not post any code. 2) I provided alternatives besides arrays if you'd like to consider those. The array is a good approach for your situation though - straightforward and functional.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, I should have. I'm sure I'll get used to this soon enough.